# How do I ensure the new code has really been deployed to target environment?

Tags: deployment, github-actions

We are using GitHub Actions to deploy our code. We have an Angular App and Laravel App in their own git repos. People usually deploy the latest code from main branch to target environment.

The delivery team claims they have deployed the code as it was during the deploy time (using git commit ID) and that's what powering the the target environment in questions. If the new code change is not reflected, is it because of cache issue in the browser or any intermediary layer or new files are not picked up by GitHub Actions?

How do I statistically and evidently verify the all the latest code from the git repo is really been taken and deployed to production? Even if people create docker image out of code, how to we ensure only the latest code (or specific git commmit/tag) is used?

How do organisations verify the code in target environment? Is it generate hash code? Or, checking the logs of updated files or some other techniques?